# django: log raw sql and als othe output

Tags: django

In django to see the logging of raw sql we can use

```
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sql'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
```

in the settings file

Is there any chance we can see the output of these raw sqls, i.e the data being fetched etc

Comment: The raw data would likely be unreadable and the string representation of a Django QuerySet only fetches the first 20 results and just uses the string representation of the model instance. What would you like the output to look like? Performance would be a worry for any large queries

Comment: Can we see string repr of the ` raw data` and also only show 2000 characters of output.

Comment: For anything that returns more than one result the executed query will return an iterator and not data, to achieve what you are suggesting I think you would have to monkey patch  the DB-API cursor class in whatever DB package you are using to log the raw data when the Django CursorWrapper requests it. You could look at patching the compiler https://github.com/django/django/blob/7582d913e7db7f32e4cdcfafc177aa77cbbf4332/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L1157

Comment: i am using `psycopg2` for postgresql database

Comment: i want to print as `python dict`